# Как в словаре в ключ записать первую строку а в значение вторую?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Существует текстовый документ, то что в нем находиться мне не известно, знаю только что первая строчка это ключ, вторая значение, третья ключ, четвертая значение, думаю понятно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно в ключ записать первую, третью и пятую строку, а в значение вторую, четвертую и шестую? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = dict()

with open('Names.txt') as file:
    try:
        while True:
            key = next(file).rstrip()
            value = next(file).rstrip()
            data[key] = value
    except StopIteration:
        pass  # Достигнут конец файла

print(data)
```

Можно также читать построчно с помощью метода `readline`, но этот метод возвращает пустую строку, если файл закончился - но для нашей задачи может быть допустим вариант, когда ключ или значение пустая строка. Поэтому удобнее получать следующую строку через `next`, он выбросит исключение `StopIteration`, когда файл закончится.

Comment: Большое спасибо, но теперь при сравнение у меня вылазит непонятная ошибка "KeyError: 'Т'"  Я обновил вопрос и кинул код, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Значит вы берете ключ "Т" и пытаетесь получить по этому ключу данные. Возможно вот здесь вы берете только первую букву от ключа: `next_keys[0]`. Не зная что у вас в `next_keys` трудно сказать из-за чего такая проблема.

Comment: В next_keys у меня первый ключ то есть слово "Первый"

Comment: Я разобрался код берет по одной букве, и использует как ключ